# How do I create custom DataObjects in Python?

Tags: python, windows, data-objects

I'm searching for the Python alternative of .NET's `DataObject` class, so I can set data and then copy the DataObject to the clipboard. Pseudocode:

```
dataobject = DataObject()
dataobject.setdata('SomeKey', 'SomeValue')
dataobject.setdata('SomeKey2', 'SomeValue2')
dataobject.copy_to_clipboard()
```

Is there any libraries for this?

Comment: want something like [THIS](http://skunkweb.sourceforge.net/PyDO/node2.html)?

Comment: @bwtrent No, I just want to create a custom data object I can copy to the Windows clipboard.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a `DataObject`, but the example you've shown looks exactly like a [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Comment: It's not a dict. I edited the example to resemble .NET's way of setting data.